# Is find() function efficient for sets?

Tags: c++, find, set

As far as I am concerned, binary search stands for the most efficient way to determine whethere there exists a certain element x in a sorted array. Thus, I was wondering if it is a good idea to make use of the find() or count() functions in order to perform this process of seeking for an element or it is more reasonable to use a sorted array rather than a set and apply the binary search method.

Comment: See [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find). `std::set::find` has logarithmic time complexity.

Comment: not to be confused with `std::find` used for a map, which has linear complexity (or more correct: which is only guaranteed to have linear complexity, a clever implementation could fall back to `std::map::find` afaik)

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is efficient.

A set contains unique and sorted elements. Therefore find() uses binary search and has a O(logN) complexity in a set of N elements. Insertion is logarithmic too, in order to keep it sorted and unique.

Comment: Bu there's far more to performance than looking at the stats.  A binary search on a sorted array/vector will also be O(log N), and will benefit from cache locality that the set implementation will lack.

Comment: That is true. Set can also be seen as a priority queue or sorted array... that is a shortcut provided by STL when we are lazy to implement them by ourselves. However, as far as complexity is concerned, set::find() is efficient.

Comment: And a linear search on an unsorted array might still be faster than a binary search on a set.

Comment: @juanchopanza for short sizes

Comment: @Attersson where "short size" can mean anything between 1 and infinity-1

Comment: The question is not asking for the most efficient solution, only if `std::set::find` is efficient. This answers that question. If the question *did* ask for **the most** efficient solution, it would be closed for being opinion based, as it would result in unproductive comment chains like this one.

Comment: Consider the slowdown as a coefficient of any size as you say. lim[N->inf] N  /  KlogN  = infinity.

Comment: @Attersson Ha. For long sizes too :-)

Answer (score 0):

`set::find()` is fairly efficient, O(log n).

If you don't need to access the elements in order, you should consider using an `unordered_set`.  `unordered_set::find()` is O(1) on average.